# any way to quickly list azure classic VMs that includes their machine type via an sdk or http api?

Tags: azure

I haven't found any azure management service endpoint that **lists** virtual machines **and** includes the instance/machine type in the output.

The only method I have found to get the machine type is by getting an individual machine rather than a list. e.g. via the node cli `azure resource show -g my-group-name -n my-resource-name -r "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines" -o "2015-10-01" --json` This works, but it is incredibly slow to fetch just a single resource. **No way** that can scale to reporting on hundreds of VMs in a reasonable manner.

What am I missing? this seems crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Azure Resource Manager](https://resources.azure.com), you can get a list of Resource Groups:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups?api-version=2014-04-01
```

and then iterate through the resource groups to get a list of Microsoft.ClassicCompute VMs:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<yourResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines?api-version=2015-06-01
```

Comment: yea, that works; it's my fallback. Problem is that second API method is super slow (~10 seconds per request). Which adds up when you have 500 VMs. Sure, there are ways around that, but I figured that surely there was a faster method. Maybe not.